# Hiding table view of search display controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want to make search display controller to work in this way:

When user press on search field it goes up to top and keyboard shows up. Normally this is happening but when user types something then shows up table view.

I don't want to do anything while user typing and when he press `Search` then  i do this:

```
 [_searchController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

and load data in my custom create table view.

How could i do this kind of functionality.

EDIT.
I found some of solution:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    savedSearchTerm = searchString;

    [controller.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.8]];
    [controller.searchResultsTableView setRowHeight:800];
    [controller.searchResultsTableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    return NO;
}
```

Maybe someone have a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `hidden` property of `searchResultsTableView`

```
controller.searchResultsTableView.hidden = YES;
```

Whenever you want it back just set `hidden` to NO and bring it to the front in case it is already displayed

```
controller.searchResultsTableView.hidden = NO;
[controller.searchResultsTableView.superview bringSubviewToFront:controller.searchResultsTableView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO];
```